# How do I return the database rows in a custom order?

Tags: database

I have a data base with two columns: a number and a name. The table is as follows:

[image]

Am expecting the result of `select * from table where num=6 or num=3` to be :

[image]

But what I get is:

[image]

How do I order the results?

Comment: Try with this - select * from table where num=3 or num=6 order by num desc;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Note:* I assume that your actual data is not just A, B, C, ..., F. Otherwise, you don't need a database for that, and can do it directly in your language ([example in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20882656/240613)).

---

You should understand the difference between *filtering* and *ordering*.

The data in the database is presented in a specific order. When a specific order is important, it is specified in the query. When not, some databases might return the rows in a nearly-nondeterministic order.

When you use `where`, you are simply *filtering* the results. Your query tells to the database:

> “Please, give me every column in a table `table`, given that I'm only interested by the rows containing `num` 6 or 3.”

While you say *what* should be returned, you don't specify in which order.

The `order by` is used exactly for that:

```
select * from table where num=3 or num=6 order by num desc
```

will return the rows in the order where the highest `num` value will appear first.

You are not limited to `asc` and `desc`, by the way. If you need, for instance, to have an order such as `6`, `7`, `2`, `3`, you can do that with `case` in Microsoft SQL Server (and similar constructs in other databases). Example:

```
select [name] from table
where num in (2, 3, 6, 7)
order by case when [num] = 6 then 1
              when [num] = 7 then 2
              when [num] = 2 then 3
              else [num] end asc
```

While this will do what you want, it's not a good solution, since you'll need to build your SQL query dynamically from user's input—thing you should avoid at all costs (because, aside poor performance, you'll end up letting SQL Injection through).

Instead:

1. Create a temporary table with two columns: an auto-incremented primary key column and a column containing numbers.
2. Insert your values (6, 7, 2, 3) in the second column.
3. Join two tables (the `table` table and the temporary table).
4. Filter on the primary key of the temporary table.
5. Remove the temporary table.

This has a benefit that you don't have to create your queries dynamically, the drawback being that the solution is slightly difficult, especially if multiple users can select the data at the same time, which means that you have to chose the name of your temporary table wisely.

The easiest solution is to **just do the filtering in your programming language** instead of the database. Load all the required rows (don't forget the `where`), and filter them later. Since, according to your comments, the user is specifying the order, I'm pretty sure you deal with only few rows, not thousands, which makes it an ideal solution. If you had to deal with hundreds of thousands of rows that you need to process as they arrive from the database without keeping them all in memory, then the previous solution with a temporary table (and a bulk insert) will be more appropriate.

Eventually, if the number of rows in the overall table is low, you don't even have to filter the data. Just load it in memory and keep it there as a map.

---

Notes:

1. Don't use `select *`. There are practically no cases where you really need it in your application. Using `select *` instead of explicitly specifying the columns has at least two drawbacks:

   - If later, a column is added, the data set you get will be different, and it might take you time to notice that and debug the related issues. Also, if a column is removed or renamed, the bugs won't be necessarily easy to find, since the errors will occur not at database level, with a clear, explicit error message, but somewhere within your application.
   - It has a performance impact, since the database needs to figure out which columns should be selected. If you do a `select *` on a table containing a few dozens of columns, including some blobs or long strings while all you need is a few columns, the performance will be quite terrible.
2. If your database supports `in`, use it:

   ```
   select * from table where num in (3, 6) order by num desc
   ```

Comment: Hi, thankyou for your reply . But my expectation is ,to get first row of result set to be with respect to first value whichever i gave before OR . example: select * from table where num=3 or num=6  should automatically give me first row name corresponding to num=3 which is C and second row should be giving me F as the output

Comment: The scenario is like this : A query needs to be written such that when a user gives two value say 6,4 then F,D should be fetched back from the database.similarly if he gives 3,5 then C,E should be written back. So order by doesnt always hold good.

Comment: = Thank you for that information, but as i have said the requirement is as given above. It is like one query should settle both my requirement. If user inputs 3,6 then since 3 is first number inputted first row should be getting result C... etc...

Comment: Why don't you filter those records using your preferred programming language, once the rows are loaded from the database? This would be unacceptable if you have hundreds of thousands of rows you should show as they arrive from the database; but you won't ask the user to specify the order of hundreds of thousands of rows, right?

Comment: at MAinma- I want to write a query that might support my requirement, i dont want my programming language to back end support it. But thank you very much for the information.I understood a lot from you

Comment: select [name] from table
where num in (2, 3, 6, 7)
order by case when [num] = 6 then 1
              when [num] = 7 then 2
              when [num] = 2 then 3
              else [num] end asc

This solved my issue but if i find any issues as you suggested i will post them. thank you very much for your reply

Comment: @RavikiranBangera: isn't your input dynamic? If yes, you won't be able to perform the operation without having to build your query dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

A common construct I have seen used in numerous database for metadata like lists is to add a column to the table with the boring name of "Column_order", a number.

Then your select is

```
select list, list_value
from your_table
where enabled = 1
order by column_order;
```

This works great in allowing any arbitrary order you want but does not work well if you have an application in multiple languages where the order might be different by language.